# Move usernames and passwords to ASP.NET Core Identity

Tags: c#, sql, .net, asp.net-core

I can get all the usernames and passwords from the current database in plain text after decryption.  I then have to throw this data into a database using Microsoft Identity for password encryption (AspNetUsers table).  I was thinking of writing a console app to use identity and convert the passwords but was wondering if there is an easier way.   I have searched and can't find any utilities to do this.   Any ideas?

Comment: You've got to have Identity integrated in your console application to do this properly with functions like [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.usermanager-1.createasync?view=aspnetcore-3.0)

Answer (score 1):

You could integrate Identity in your console application and add users into database follow the steps below:

1.Add the following packages:

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity" Version="2.2.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="2.2.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="2.2.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="2.2.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="2.2.0">
  <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
  <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers</IncludeAssets>
</PackageReference>
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration" Version="2.2.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection" Version="2.2.0" />
```

2.Create a Models directory and create `ApplicationUser` and `ApplicationDbContext`

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
}

public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }
}
```

3. Add a class that implements [IDesignTimeDbContextFactory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/cli/dbcontext-creation#from-a-design-time-factory)

```
    public class ApplicationDbContextFactory:IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<ApplicationDbContext>
    {
      public ApplicationDbContext CreateDbContext(string[] args)
      {
        var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<ApplicationDbContext>();
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=ConsoleAppIdentity;Trusted_Connection=True;ConnectRetryCount=0");

        return new ApplicationDbContext(optionsBuilder.Options);
      }
    }
```

4.Add and execute a mingration

```
PM> add-migration CreateInitial
PM> update-database
```

5.Code for Program.cs

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var services = new ServiceCollection();

        //setup our DI
        // Add framework services.            
        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options=> {
            options.UseSqlServer("Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=ConsoleAppIdentity;Trusted_Connection=True;ConnectRetryCount=0");
        });

        services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

        services.AddScoped<IUserCreationService, UserCreationService>();

        // Build the IoC from the service collection
        var provider = services.BuildServiceProvider();

        var userService = provider.GetService<IUserCreationService>();

        userService.CreateUser().GetAwaiter().GetResult();

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    public interface IUserCreationService
    {
        Task CreateUser();
    }

    public class UserCreationService : IUserCreationService
    {
        public readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager;

        public UserCreationService(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager)
        {
            this.userManager = userManager;
        }

        public async Task CreateUser()
        {
            var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = "TestUser", Email = "test@example.com" };
            var result = await this.userManager.CreateAsync(user, "Test@123");

            if (result.Succeeded == false)
            {
                foreach (var error in result.Errors)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(error.Description);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Done.");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This looks like it will work but I would worry about defining ApplicationUser and context inside the Console App. Ideally they would be in a shareable library.